# Phone can't send SMS message from APP, in emulator work great

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sms, smsmanager

I have to make a mega-simple app that, when a button is pressed, reads the number entered in the text field and sends an SMS to that number. The last time I had contact with Java was a couple of years ago but I managed to stick something out there with the help of the Internet. The code for the SMS sending itself looks like this:

```
package com.example.nextchat;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        int PERMISSION_ALL = 1;
        String[] PERMISSIONS = {
                Manifest.permission.READ_SMS,
                Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS,
                Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS,
        };

        if (!hasPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);
        }

        Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SmsManager sm = SmsManager.getDefault();
                sm.sendTextMessage("48123456789", null, "Bla bla bla", null, null);
            }
        });
    }

    public static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
        if (context != null && permissions != null) {
            for (String permission : permissions) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

I added the necessary permissions to the file AndroidManifest.XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.nextchat">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Nextchat"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I checked in the emulator and everything works, the message shows as sent in the device. The problem occurred when I generated the APK file and wanted to test the code on a real phone. The app launches normally and asks for permissions to send and read SMS. However, the problem is that the SMS admittedly shows up in the default SMS app and even matches the contact based on the number but the message does not send. With every such message I get the message "Not sent. Touch to try again. Of course, when I touch, the message sends correctly. I have tried on two phones, one with Android 12, the other Android 10, and in both cases the same error occurs. Do any of you know what this could be about? I accept any advice because I have no idea what is going on.

Comment: Usually that message means you have connectivity issues.  Did the devices have a valid working sim, and could you make a call on them?  Remember SMS is sent over the carrier not over the net, so wifi won't work-  it needs to be a cellular connection.

Comment: @GabeSechan thanks for answer. The phone and sim card definitely work because when I click on the sms that my app didn't send it sends right away.